# Call method by argument type

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to generify part of JPA Specification.

This what I have:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeObjectSpecification implements Specification<SomeObject> {

    private final SearchCriteria criteria;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<SomeObject> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        switch (criteria.getOperation()) {
            case ":":
                return getLikePredicate(root, criteriaBuilder, criteria.getValue());
    ...
    }

    private <T extends Temporal>Predicate getLikePredicate(
            Root<SomeObject> root,
            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
            T value) {
    ...
    }

    private <T extends CharSequence> Predicate getLikePredicate(
            Root<OrderSummaryView> root,
            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
            T value) {
    ...
    }   
}
```

And SearchCriteria:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Comparable value;
}
```

I would like to enter first `getLikePredicate` whenever `LocalDateTime` is passed, and enter second one, while I have `String` in hand.

No matter how I try, I can call only second method, no idea how to enter first one, when I have `LocalDateTime` in `SearchCriteria.value`

Comment: Method binding is done at *compile* time, not *runtime*. Basically, you can't do what you want to do here. Your only choice is to name the private methods differently and use reflection to discover the type of the criteria value and invoke the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing `implements Specification<SomeObject>` and overriding the method `toPredicate(Root<SomeObject> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder)`.

As a result, the `root` parameter will always have the type `Root<SomeObject>`. therefore you'll always call the first method that has the `Root<SomeObject>` parameter and you'll never call the one with `Root<OrderSummaryView>`.

When you have multiple methods with the same name, but different arguments - this is called "overloading" and the correct method is chosen based the parameters, not on the return type.